# Работа с json

Tags: java, android, json

Здравствуйте. С сервера приходят данные в виде json массива

Код парсера:

```
  JSONObject json = ...
  try  { 
  .. = json.getString ( ..)
  .. = json.getJSONArray(..)
  цикл по jsonarray 
 } 
catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Cтандратный парсер json. Работает хорошо, но предположим ситуацию у нас есть ссылка, где нету json массива. Программа не сможет его разобрать и упадет. Поэтому нужно сделать проверку JSONObject на null. 
Как я предполагаю , нужно сделать так:

```
 JSONObject json = ...
 if (json == null ) {
 // тут уже есть null json 
 }
 try  {
```

Правильно ?

Comment: смотря что приходит по ссылке, по идее, то что у вас обернуто в try-catch, уже дролжно обработать этот случай

Comment: покажите же самое интересное - что скрывается за `...`. В зависимости от этого и нужно будет смотреть. Но судя по документации и, понимая, что там скорее всего будет конструктор, то там будет исключение. Поэтому

    try {
      JSONObject json = ...;
    }
    catch (JSONException) {
      // show except message
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код парсера:

```
 try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

    return jObj;

}
```

В том и дело, что по логу :

```
 E/JSON Parser(944): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Оно ловит исключение, а мне надо, чтобы оно поймало его и не закрыло приложение, а хотя бы выдало сообщение toast, а оно просто закрывает приложение и сообщение не появляется.

Вот сюда я добавлял toast сообщение

```
   try {
   JSONObject json = ...;
  }
catch (JSONException) {
 // show except message
  Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Слышали о ключевом слове finally в блоке try/catch? Сделайте так.

```
JSONObject json = null;

try {
    json = ... // работа
} catch {
   // обработка ошибки
} finally {
   if (json == null) {
       Toast.make.... // показываем сообщение
   }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло ( Как вылетало, так и вылетает. В лог пишется  Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:, то есть исключение идет, но почему то приложение падает на этом

Comment: почему "iso-8859-1"?? поставь utf-8